# Perl array and string as method arguments

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a method where I give two arguments: ***one array and one string***. The problem is when I initialise two different variables, one for the array and one for the string, I get the first element of the array in the first variable and the second element in the second variable. My question is how can I get the whole array in a variable and the string in a different variable?

**Analyze.pm**

```
sub analyze {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($content, $stringToSearch) = @_; 
    # my ($stringToSearch) = @_;
    print "$stringToSearch";
    if (!defined($stringToSearch) or length($stringToSearch) == 0) { die 'stringToSearch is not defined yet! ' }
    foreach my $element ($content) {
        #print "$element";
        my $loc = index($element, $stringToSearch);
        # print "$loc\n";
        given ($stringToSearch) {
            when ($stringToSearch eq "Hi") {
                if ($loc != 0) {
                    print "Searched word is Hi \n"; 
                } else {
                    print "No word found like this one! "
                }
            }
            #when ($stringToSearch == 'ORIENTED_EDGE') {
            #   print 'Searched word is ORIENTED_EDGE';
            #} # Printed out because i dont need it now!
        }
        break; # For testing
    }
}
```

**example.pm**

```
my @fileContent = ('Hi', 'There', 'Its', 'Me')
my $analyzer = Analyze->new();
$analyzer->analyze(@fileContent, 'Hi');
```

When I change `$content` to `@content` it puts all the values of the array and the string in `@content`

I hope someone is able to help me. I'm a beginner in Perl. Thanks in advance

Comment: swap them?call analyze('Hi',@content) instead

Comment: easy to mess up with $ and @ , so i would suggest put all $ args in front of any @ arg , or use dict as arg completely

Comment: As an aside: `break` is not a Perl keyword. What you want here is probably `last`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass arrays to subs (or methods), only a list of scalars. As such,

```
$analyzer->analyze(@lines, 'Hi');
```

is the same as as

```
$analyzer->analyze($lines[0], $lines[1], ..., 'Hi');
```

It means that the following won't work well:

```
my (@strings, $target) = @_;
```

Perl doesn't know how many items belonged to the original array, so it places them all in `@strings`, leaving `$target` undefined.

---

**Solutions**

You can do what you want as follows:

```
sub analyze {
    my $self = shift;
    my $target = pop;
    my @strings = @_
    for my $string (@strings) {
       ...
    }
}

$analyzer->analyze(@lines, 'Hi')
```

Or without the needless copy:

```
sub analyze {
    my $self = shift;
    my $target = pop;
    for my $string (@_) {
       ...
    }
}

$analyzer->analyze(@lines, 'Hi')
```

Passing the target first can be easier.

```
sub analyze {
    my ($self, $target, @strings) = @_;
    for my $string (@strings) {
       ...
    }
}

$analyzer->analyze('Hi', @lines)
```

Or without the needless copy:

```
sub analyze {
    my $self = shift;
    my $target = shift;
    for my $string (@_) {
       ...
    }
}

$analyzer->analyze('Hi', @lines)
```

You could also pass a reference to the array (in any order you like) since a reference is a scalar.

```
sub analyze {
    my ($self, $target, $strings) = @_;
    for my $string (@$strings) {
       ...
    }
}

$analyzer->analyze('Hi', \@lines)
```

I would go with the second to last. It follows the same general pattern as the well-known `grep`.

```
my @matches = grep { condition($_) } @strings;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm a new to perl so I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add a slightly different method of passing an array to a subroutine.

```
# Begin main program
my @arr=(1,2,3);
my $i=0;
mysub(\@arr,$i); # Pass the reference to the array

exit; # Exit main program
##########
sub mysub
{my($aref,$i)=@_; # We are receiving an array ref. 

my @arr=@$aref; # Now we are back to a regular array.
print "$arr[0]\n$arr[1]\n$arr[2]\n";

return;
}
```

Comment: Passing a reference was already mentioned. All you added is `my @arr=@$aref;`. **That's awful! Don't even do that!!!** You're copying all the elements for nothing!

Comment: @ikegami It's not awful, it helps beginners understand how references work. This shouldn't be an elitist site for advanced people only.